# How to cause fetch calls to queue up once I've reached max number of concurrent calls?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, rest, redux

I have code that will make a number of concurrent calls to a piece of software that provides a rest interface to query our system.  We recently discovered that a sufficiently high number of concurrent calls (somewhere between 30 to 100) can cause the software to fail and actually break the backed functionality.

As a work around I'd  like to fix this by having my code block if more then X concurrent calls are outstanding, sending new calls only after the old calls resolve.  As I already have a number of outstanding UIs I'd also prefer to change this behavior by updating a shared lower level Request method.

My 'request' method returns a promise, which is ultimately called within a redux Saga in each UI via the 'call' redux-effect.  This means I need to be able to return a promise from my Request method, which means figuring some way to return a promise that won't try to resolve a Request until the earlier Requests resolve.

I started to write my own, but there is no easy way for me to 'alert' a promise, to tell it that previous promises have completed.  The best way to roll my own I was able to figure out involved using Promise.race and then having the exact same callNextQueued method called for both the resolve and reject method, and generally it just feels kind of ugly conceptually.

Is there a better way to implement this?  either an API that already does it, or a clean way to work with promises to role my own logic for starting a new request whenever any old request completes?

Comment: [Swimmer](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/swimmer) might be a nice alternative for this.

Comment: @Tholle hmm, that is what I was thinking of.  Unfortunately when I thought about using it I realized I needed a way to cancel the queued requests when someone switches which site they want to query, and of course promises can't be cancled.  That probably means bluebird and none of the promise throttle tools I've found promise they can work with bluebird.  I feel like this shouldn't be this hard lol.

Comment: I see. You could e.g. have a variable `isActive` that you set to `false` if the user changes which site to query, and in all your promises you check that `isActive` is still `true`. Sure, there will be a ton of redundant promises in the chain that do nothing at all, but that might work. You can also stop a Swimmer  pool with `pool.stop()`